Emily Riehl's proof of density theorem for non-small categories
$\def\C{\mathsf{C}}
\def\J{\mathsf{J}}
\def\D{\mathsf{D}}$I am interested in the proof of the density theorem in Riehl's Category Theory in Context [R, 6.5.7]. Before stating the result, I will copy here two results that are invoked in the proof of [R, 6.5.7].

[R, Theorem 3.4.12.] The colimit of any small diagram $F: \J \rightarrow \mathsf{C}$ may be expressed as a coequalizer of a pair of maps between coproducts
$$
\coprod_{f \in \operatorname{mor} \J} F(\operatorname{dom} f) \underset{c}{\overset{d}{\rightrightarrows}} \coprod_{j \in \operatorname{ob} \J} F j \longrightarrow \operatorname{colim}_\J F.
$$
[R, Proposition 6.5.6 (coYoneda lemma)]. For any small diagram $F: \mathsf{C} \rightarrow \mathsf{D}$ valued in a category with coproducts and coequalizers, there is a coequalizer diagram
$$
\coprod_{y \rightarrow x \rightarrow c} F y \longrightarrow \coprod_{x \rightarrow c} F x \longrightarrow F c
$$
in which one of the parallel maps includes the component indexed by $y \rightarrow x \rightarrow c$ as the component indexed by the composite morphism $y \rightarrow c$, while the other acts by $F$ on the map $y \rightarrow x$ and then includes as the component indexed by the map $x \rightarrow c$.

Here is the statement and proof of the density theorem as in Riehl's book:

[R, Theorem 6.5.7 (density I)]. For any locally small category $\C$, any functor $F : \C \rightarrow\mathsf{Set}$  is the colimit of the diagram
$$
\int F^{\mathrm{op}} \xrightarrow{\Pi} \C^{\mathrm{op}} \xrightarrow{y} \mathsf{Set}^{\C}
$$
which is indexed by the opposite of the category $\int F$ of elements of $F$ and takes values in the subcategory of representable functors. Dually, any $F: \C^{\mathrm{op}} \rightarrow\mathsf{Set}$ is the colimit of
$$
\int F \xrightarrow{\Pi} \C \xrightarrow{y} \mathsf{Set}^{\C^{\mathrm{op}}}
$$
Proof. For sets $S$ and $T$, there are isomorphisms $\coprod_S T \cong S \times T \cong \coprod_T S$, so the coequalizer given by the coYoneda lemma is isomorphic to the coequalizer${ }^8$
$$
\coprod_{F y \times \C(y, x)} \C(x, c) \longrightarrow \coprod_{Fx} \C(x, c) \longrightarrow F c \text {, }
$$
where the indexing sets have been swapped. Letting $c$ vary, we conclude that $F$ is canonically a colimit of a diagram of representable functors. Reversing Theorem 3.4.12, the indexing category for this diagram of representables is one whose objects are elements of the set $F x$ for some $x \in \C$ and whose morphisms are maps $y \rightarrow x$ in $\C$ that send the chosen element of $F y$ to the corresponding element of $F x$. Thus, $F$ is the colimit of the canonical diagram
$$
\int F^{\mathrm{op}} \xrightarrow{\Pi} \C^{\mathrm{op}} \xrightarrow{y} \mathsf{Set}^{\C} .\quad\square
$$

${ }^8$If $\C$ is not small, then the displayed coproducts, which are tacitly indexed by the objects of $\C$, are not small. Nonetheless, Theorem 6.3.7, which expresses $F c$ as a colimit of a large diagram \eqref{eq}, tells us that $F$ is a colimit of a diagram indexed by the large category $\int F$.

Where footnote ${ }^8$ refers to the equation
$$
\tag{6.5.5}\label{eq}
Fc\cong\operatorname{colim}(\C/c\xrightarrow{\Pi}\C\xrightarrow{F}\D)
$$
that holds for any functor $F:\C\to\D$. This isomorphism is obtained from Theorem 6.3.7 plus the observation that any functor is a pointwise left Kan extension of itself along the identity of its domain.
Now my problem: I understand Riehl's proof of the density theorem if $\C$ were small. I intuit that footnote $^8$ hints at how one could adapt the proof in the case $\C$ is big (i.e., not small), but I don't see how. How does one do it? Wikipedia's more direct proof works for $\C$ of arbitrary size (and I understand this other proof). I am nonetheless interested in understanding how one would apply Riehl's strategy in the non-small case.
References
[R] E. Riehl, Category Theory in Context
